# App crashes after building with Proguard

Tags: android, crash, proguard

My app built and ran successfully, then I enabled Proguard and now the app crashes immediately on launch.  There are no build errors, only runtime/launch crashes.  I am using Android Studio 1.1.0.  Target API 22, min 14.

How can I track down what Proguard is doing to make the app crash on startup?  I found the location of the output files but I don't know what to look for.  I have searched through dozens of Proguard tips online but so far nothing helps. Below is my proguard.cfg:

```
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,InnerClasses,Exceptions,EnclosingMethod
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    

-dontwarn com.facebook.**
-dontwarn com.httpmime.**
-dontwarn com.parse.**

-keep class UserLoginTask
-keep class UserPasswordRecoveryTask
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.pictureplay.BitmapWorkerTask
-keep public class com.pictureplay.App
-keep public class com.pictureplay.DrawingView
-keep public class com.pictureplay.Exif_Reader
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}
-keep public class * extends android.os.AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
-keep class com.pictureplay.LoginActivity { *; }
-keep class com.pictureplay.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask { *; }
-keep class com.pictureplay.LoginActivity$UserPasswordRecoveryTask { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.pictureplay.UserLoginTask**
-keepclassmembers class com.pictureplay.UserPasswordRecoveryTask** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    Boolean doInBackground(...);
    void onPostExecute*(...);
 }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}
```

Comment: in android studio you should be using minifyEnabled instead of Proguard

Comment: First of all you should post crash in your question.

Comment: Yes, I use minifyEnabled true to use Proguard, and minifyEnabled false to build without Proguard.  When I use minifyEnabled true is when the app crashes on launch.  When set to false, the app runs fine.  The file size looks like it's being shrunk either way, compared to when I was using Eclipse (I just switched to Android Studio a week ago).

Comment: What do you mean, "post crash in my question?"  There was no crash report that I know of, it just says, "Unfortunately, Picture Play has stopped".  This is my first Android project.

Comment: I have the same problem : when I added proguard in release version (minifyEnabled and proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt' in build.gradle, my app crash àat launch with an horrible "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError". Now when I suppress proguard, it's running fine !!!

Comment: Every time I get Proguard working, I then make some changes to my app and Proguard breaks it again.  I think it's going to work best to separate out the part that most needs obfuscating into a separate class and only use Proguard on that class.  That way I will only have to fix it once.